# How to install package with apt-get in Gitlab CI pipeline using micromamba image

Tags: python, docker, gitlab-ci, miniconda, mamba

I'm using the [micromamba](https://hub.docker.com/r/mambaorg/micromamba) image in a Gitlab CI pipeline. I need to install an additional package with apt-get (libgl1-mesa-glx).

With the miniconda image this was working:

```
image: continuumio/miniconda3:latest

before_script:
  - apt-get update && apt-get install -y libgl1-mesa-glx
```

With micromamba, it does not work anymore:

```
image: mambaorg/micromamba:1.1.0-bullseye

before_script:
  - apt-get update && apt-get install -y libgl1-mesa-glx
```

results in

```
Reading package lists...
E: List directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial is missing. - Acquire (13: Permission denied)
```

Is this possible at all? Or do I need to generate a custom docker image?

Comment: Looks like you might need sudo?

Comment: @MichaelDelgado Wouldn't that be a security risk?

Answer (score 2):

This is because the user you are running the command from is root or non-sudo user. In the first repo, the user automatically comes with root privileges. That's why you can run commands that require sudo authority.

This is explained on the official Dockerhub pages:

> Changing the user id or name The default username is stored in the
> environment variable MAMBA_USER, and is currently mambauser. (Before
> 2022-01-13 it was micromamba, and before 2021-06-30 it was root.)
> Micromamba-docker can be run with any UID/GID by passing the docker
> run ... command the --user=UID: GID parameters. Running with
> --user=root is supported....

Please look at the "Changing the user id or name" section of this [page](https://hub.docker.com/r/mambaorg/micromamba).
This problem has several solution, it might be help;

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/248/designs

Comment: https://hub.docker.com/r/mambaorg/micromamba#advanced-usages Talks about building an image, but I just want to use the existing image from the Docker Hub in my pipeline. Can I somehow change the user in my .gitlab-ci.yml file?

Comment: I also don't really understand why in the first repo, the user is root by default. Isn't that a security risk?

Comment: This is pretty common in docker files which are intended to be built upon. You can always change the user.